# Convert binary to char or char to binary

Tags: binary, char

I know we can convert binary to char by any program but I wanna know how to convert that by myself.
For example;
1010111 == W but how I can find that myself?

Comment: Convert the numeric value (from binary) to decimal or hexadecimal, then find out what it corresponds to in ASCII table (for smaller numbers), or look at Unicode charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert binary to decimal which is 87
then you refer to the ascii table for number 87 which is W

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this table https://www.asciitable.com/.
It doesn't have direct binary to ascii mapping but you can convert binary to base of 10 and lookup